# Azure DevOps Charts with Custom Field

Tags: azure-devops

I need to create a chart from a query in Azure DevOps using a custom field of User Story. But I see only the predefined fields while creating charts.

[image]

How to create charts using Custom Fields in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your custom field a column selected by the query? If it is of the appropriate type, this may be all that is necessary.

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/charts?toc=%2fazure%2fdevops%2fboards%2fqueries%2ftoc.json&%3bbc=%2fazure%2fdevops%2fboards%2fqueries%2fbreadcrumb%2ftoc.json&view=azure-devops#create-a-query-based-chart):

> If you don't see the field you want in the Group by drop-down list, add the field as a column to the query and save the query. You can group by any field except date-time and free-form text fields. For example:
>
> - To group by work assignments, include the Assigned To in the query or column options
> - To group by sprints or iterations, include the Iteration Path in the query or column options
> - To group by team, include the Area Path or Node Name in the query or column options
> - To group by a custom field, include it in a query clause or column options.

There may be an issue with the type of field you are trying to use, but it's hard to give any additional information from your screenshot as I can't see the type of chart you're trying to make or to which chart field you're trying to assign this custom work item field.

#### Illustration:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I realized the custom filed has to be added as a column in the query to group it in the chart.